# Base64 encoding and check

Tags: java, image, encoding, base64

i'm working on a batch image send in java. The image should be base64 encoded. I used for this the Apache Commons Codec library.
This is the code i use for encoding

```
            String lines="";  
        String encodedLines="";
        StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
        try(InputStream is = new FileInputStream(filename);
              BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))
                 ){


              String line;
              while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                  sb.append(line);
              }


          }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw(e);
            }

        lines=sb.toString();
        encodedLines = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(lines.getBytes()));
```

Then i checked the result using https://www.base64-image.de/ and i notice that the encoded image on the site is completely different. Tried both with png and jpg.

What could be wrong with my encoding ?

Comment: Image data is not stored in Text format. It is binary. Just read all the bytes from the image file.

Comment: Don't store or treat binary data like string data, readFileToByteArray then encode that.

Comment: An image is pure binary data. Not lines of text. Don't read it as text. Read it as bytes. Also, StringBuffer shouldn't be used for years and years. Use StringBuilder.